# What happens internally when a file is modified and saved?

Tags: file, operating-system, filesystems

What happens internally when a file is modified and saved? Will the OS allocates a new block of memory and copy the whole data or only the bits after the modified part are shifted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files are manipulated in blocks. A block on disk is like a byte in memory. You can only read and write in units of blocks. 512 bytes used to be the normal block size but 4096 is more common now.

The OS will read the entire block into memory; change whatever bytes; then write the entire block to the disk.

Clusters are units of file allocation. They are multiples of blocks. The disk hardware is generally unaware of clusters. Larger cluster sizes reduce the amount of system allocation overhead but are inefficient for large numbers of small files. You can read and write individual blocks within a cluster.

Answer (score -1):

Diferent methods are for each one, remember we have diferent file systems. for example in ntfs when u write a file and it uses for example six cluster it will be like that in your file sistem:

```
123456
```

if u add a new file using 1 cluster it will be like that

```
1234561
```

so now u remove that first file:

```
      1
```

and u will write a new file using 3 clusters

```
123   1
```

and now u want to write a file with 7 clusters

```
12312314567
```

for example if u want to copy a file in another folder it will be re written in new clusters in your filesystem, but if u want to cut it u will modify only the INDEX thats why is so fast cut files versus copy action.

so if u modify a file a part or complete in the most cases will be loaded in a buffer and then when u save your changes that buffer is written in the hard disk replacing the afected clusters and writting the new ones. But that depends cause diferent software uses diferent methods.

Comment: in the fourth case will the OS leave 3 clusters and save it as 123   1 or will it be saved as 1231. I think contiguous memory will be given to a file

Comment: will be 123   1  that event is called file system fragmentation.

Comment: Deep explanation about cluster size and ntfs estructure
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134%28v=ws.10%29.aspx